# Is there any Recipe to move a file from one location to another?

Tags: openrewrite

for a smooth migration I'm looking for a recipe in Open-Rewrite to move a file (in that case a configuration File which always has the same name) from one location (for example C:\project\mymodule\test.conf) to another (for example C:\project\mymodule\v2\test.conf).

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Had you come across the [Rename a file](https://docs.openrewrite.org/reference/recipes/core/renamefile) recipe?

```
---
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: com.yourorg.RenameFileExample
displayName: Rename a file example
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.RenameFile:
      fileMatcher: '**/application-*.yml'
      fileName: application.yml
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that recipe, but i can't change  the directory of the renamed File or did I missed anything?

Comment: You can just add the directory name as part of `fileName`.